# Error unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied on docker push registry.gitlab.com

Tags: gitlab, docker-registry

I have error with:

```
docker push registry.gitlab.com/user/rep-name

The push refers to repository [registry.gitlab.com/user/rep]
f319ccdf8ee4: Preparing 
..
7032a7172c0a: Preparing 
b16cd70f3a2c: Waiting 
...
unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied
```

But prev login is Succeeded:

```
docker login registry.gitlab.com
Username: user
Password: 
Login Succeeded
```

Docker ver:

```
docker -v
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
```

I use Personal Access Token is "api"
https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens

because I have 2-factor athorization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I change:

- Personal Access Token scope:
  https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens to "api" and "read_registry"
- usename in docker login from @user to user@example.com

now it is works.

Seems issue is in "read_registry" scope.
And it is strange because "api" also have read access.
From Gitlab:

> Grants complete **read**/write access to the API, including all groups and
> projects, the **container registry**, and the package registry.

Comment: No need to check `api`.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didn't work for me.

In my case - I too had SSO - had to use the token name instead of my username/email

1. Generated a token with read_registry and api persmission
2. `docker login -u <PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME> -p <PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY> registry.gitlab.com`

Hope this helps someone.