# Docker login: access denied you must use a personal access token

Tags: docker, gitlab

Trying to login from docker to gitlab using the command:

```
sudo docker login registry.gitlab.com?private_token=XXX
```

But I still have the following error message:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/: unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied\nYou must use a personal access token with 'api' scope for Git over HTTP.\nYou can generate one at https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens
```

The token has the right access I doubled checked... I am rather new to docker, any hint/help? thanks!

Comment: Possibly related question: [Error unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied on docker push registry.gitlab.com - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197872/error-unauthorized-http-basic-access-denied-on-docker-push-registry-gitlab-com)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The correct command line (that works in my case at least) was:

```
docker login registry.example.com -u <your_username> -p <your_personal_access_token>
```

Comment: As a side note, it's usually considered better practice to enter the token interactively. Meaning that you omit the `-p <token>` portion of the command and instead enter the token in STDIN when prompted. This way the token won't ever show up in your shell history or be visible on your screen.

Comment: What the hell is my username? I've tried GitLab Email and Username, doesn't work.

Comment: @kingsfoil If you are doing this as part of a CICD pipeline it's a no go. Rather use some sort of a CICD variable (e.g. the ones in GitLab that can then be called inside the YML pipeline configuration file).

Comment: @kingsfoil For some strange reason, for me, entering it interactively wasn't working but this method with the flag did.  I was copy/pasting, so it can't even have been a typo.  But at least this worked as a backup (however insecure).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using 2 factor authentication, then personal access tokens are required.

More information on the following webpage,

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html

Comment: Yes I have 2fa on my gitlab account, that why in my command line I do `private_token=XXX`

Comment: On the link, there is a section on Limiting scope of a personal access token, and from your error you do not seem to have the api permission.

Comment: `docker login registry.gitlab.com -u <username> -p >personal_access_token>`

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html, your username actually gets ignored:

> Though required, GitLab usernames are ignored when authenticating with a personal access token. There is an issue for tracking to make GitLab use the username.

So, if you're not able to connect, it might not be because of the username.