# Gitlab: Unauthorized: Basic http basic access denied

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab

I'm getting Error response from daemon https://registry.com unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied on docker login registry.com:8443

I created a gitlab user and password in the gitlab registry and tried to do docker login from the K8s cluster. it is throwing the above error.

This is happening after upgrading the gitlab from 13.12.1 to 14.0.1.

I tried to reset the password from the gitlab UI and it didn't work for me.

Thanks

Comment: I hope you can appreciate that with such an overwhelming level of detail, including what troubleshooting steps you've already tried, no one can possibly help you on a _programming_ stack exchange. Please do consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68229528/edit) and include what you have already tried to resolve this and the outcome of those experiments

Comment: Probably same question as [gitlab - Docker login: access denied you must use a personal access token - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072379/docker-login-access-denied-you-must-use-a-personal-access-token?noredirect=1&lq=1) , but there's too little details here to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I logged to gitlab UI with the gitlab user i created . It prompted to reset the password. After resetting the password, the docker login registry.com:8443     command successfully logged in to the gitlab registry.